# how product categories can be displayed in woocommerce using custom code

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, widget, categories

I want to display product categories to display vendors by categories while right now categories are used to display products.

So if you can guide me how categories can be displayed by custom code or how woo-commerce widget can be updated or customized.

I google it but it takes me to existing widget and detail of widget to display categories but nowhere i can find what i'm looking for.

Comment: Question is still bit unclear. Do you want to show just category listings?

Comment: yes, i want category listing but when i click it it does not redirect to product-category page, it should redirect to some custome page (vendor-category). @MahaDev it would be really appreciated if you ca help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work manually like this:

```
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'field' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false
    );

    $all_cats = get_categories($args);

    foreach ($all_cats as $cat){

        echo $cat->term_id;
        echo $cat->taxonomy;

    }
```

It will display all the categories. now you have to set a custom anchor href for vendor category.

Comment: Write only 'name' instead of term_name.  Like this `echo $cat->name;`